# Кросскомпиляция под виндовс на линукс

Tags: windows, ubuntu, cmake, кросс-компиляция

Уважаемые форумчане, встретился с проблемой. Мне нужно скомпилировать проект под виндовс, но это всё делается на ubuntu 18.04, а на ней в cmake нет генератора mingw.

Пошагово, что я делал:

```
cmake -S /... -B /... -G "MinGW Makefiles"
```

После чего получаю ошибку

```
CMake Error: Could not create named generator Mingw Makefiles
```

Каким образом можно с ubuntu скомпилировать проект для других ОС. Заранее спасибо за помощь!)

P.S. ставить все библиотеки на винду очень геморно и должен быть адекватный способ сделать это на линуксе

Comment: Поставь qt-sdk в wine. Для настройки mingw нужно очень много - для проектов без автоматизации я б не тратил на это силы

Comment: В складывающейся обстановке я бы вообще больше не тратил силы на винду

Comment: Вообще для этого есть прекрасная тула: mxe - почитайте о ней, замечательная штука

Answer (score 1, accepted):

как написано в [документации](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/-/wikis/doc/cmake/cross_compiling/Mingw), для сборки [portable executable](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable) при помощи *mingw32*, всё что надо — это задействовать «toolchain-файл». [минимальный пример файла](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/uploads/265a703419aeaa26bef8044b92911e37/Toolchain-cross-mingw32-linux.cmake) приведён там же.

указать его можно с помощью опции `-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE`:

```
$ cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=путь.к.toolchain-файлу другие.аргументы
```

---

демонстрация (на основе упомянутого примера):

1. устанавливаю в docker-образе («для чистоты эксперимента», для чистоты же беру образ постарее — `debian:8`) пакеты: `cmake mingw32 make file` (последний — лишь для проверки результата).
2. скачиваю в текущий каталог [пример](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/uploads/265a703419aeaa26bef8044b92911e37/Toolchain-cross-mingw32-linux.cmake) «toolchain-файла»:

   ```
   $ cat Toolchain-cross-mingw32-linux.cmake
   # the name of the target operating system
   SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Windows)

   # Choose an appropriate compiler prefix

   # for classical mingw32
   # see http://www.mingw.org/
   #set(COMPILER_PREFIX "i586-mingw32msvc")

   # for 32 or 64 bits mingw-w64
   # see http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/
   set(COMPILER_PREFIX "i686-w64-mingw32")
   #set(COMPILER_PREFIX "x86_64-w64-mingw32"

   # which compilers to use for C and C++
   find_program(CMAKE_RC_COMPILER NAMES ${COMPILER_PREFIX}-windres)
   #SET(CMAKE_RC_COMPILER ${COMPILER_PREFIX}-windres)
   find_program(CMAKE_C_COMPILER NAMES ${COMPILER_PREFIX}-gcc)
   #SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER ${COMPILER_PREFIX}-gcc)
   find_program(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER NAMES ${COMPILER_PREFIX}-g++)
   #SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER ${COMPILER_PREFIX}-g++)


   # here is the target environment located
   SET(USER_ROOT_PATH /home/erk/erk-win32-dev)
   SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH  /usr/${COMPILER_PREFIX} ${USER_ROOT_PATH})

   # adjust the default behaviour of the FIND_XXX() commands:
   # search headers and libraries in the target environment, search
   # programs in the host environment
   set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
   set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
   set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
   ```
3. создаю файл с исходниками и с правилами для *cmake*:

   ```
   $ cat main.c 
   #include <stdio.h>

   int main()
   {
      printf("Hello world\n");
      return 0;
   }

   $ cat CMakeLists.txt 
   ADD_EXECUTABLE(hello main.c)
   ```
4. генерирую `makefile` и прочее «cmake-овское хозяйство»:

   ```
   $ cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=./Toolchain-cross-mingw32-linux.cmake .
   -- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.9.1
   -- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.9.1
   -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-gcc
   -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-gcc -- works
   -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
   -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
   -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-g++
   -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-g++ -- works
   -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
   -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
   -- Configuring done
   -- Generating done
   -- Build files have been written to: .
   ```
5. запускаю *make*:

   ```
   $ make
   Scanning dependencies of target hello
   [100%] Building C object CMakeFiles/hello.dir/main.c.obj
   Linking C executable hello.exe
   [100%] Built target hello
   ```
6. проверяю, что же получилось:

   ```
   $ file hello.exe 
   hello.exe: PE32 executable (console) Intel 80386, for MS Windows
   ```